# For Loop Pl/SQL with specified lower and upper bound

Tags: sql, for-loop, counter

do I want to use this simple loop:

FOR indx IN 1 .. l_table_with_227_rows.COUNT

but instead of using 1..row.count , I want to specify lower and upper bound from an array or a column ..
Example: employee_ID[1] .. employee_ID[10]
keep in mind that I want to change them when repeat the loop by sliding them 
so next will be
employee_ID[11] .. employee_ID[20]

Do you know if that is possible? 
I've been looking for an answer for that for so long

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the values of the array to specify the lower bound and upper bound values for the `FOR` loop.

For example, let's say we have an employee table with data as below:

```
create table EMPLOYEES (id number, name varchar2(20), title varchar2(30), salary number);

insert into EMPLOYEES values (1, 'Jim', 'App Specialist', 1000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (2, 'Joseph', 'App Specialist', 2000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (3, 'John', 'App Specialist', 3000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (4, 'James', 'App Specialist', 4000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (5, 'Jack', 'App Specialist', 5000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (6, 'Jim', 'App Specialist', 1000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7, 'Joseph', 'App Specialist', 2000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (8, 'John', 'App Specialist', 3000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (9, 'James', 'App Specialist', 4000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (10, 'Jack', 'App Specialist', 5000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (11, 'Jim', 'App Specialist', 1000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (12, 'Joseph', 'App Specialist', 2000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (13, 'John', 'App Specialist', 3000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (14, 'James', 'App Specialist', 4000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (15, 'Jack', 'App Specialist', 5000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (16, 'Jim', 'App Specialist', 1000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (17, 'Joseph', 'App Specialist', 2000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (18, 'John', 'App Specialist', 3000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (19, 'James', 'App Specialist', 4000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (20, 'Jack', 'App Specialist', 5000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (21, 'Jim', 'App Specialist', 1000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (22, 'Joseph', 'App Specialist', 2000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (23, 'John', 'App Specialist', 3000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (24, 'James', 'App Specialist', 4000);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (25, 'Jack', 'App Specialist', 5000);
commit;
```

The following procedure includes a `FOR` loop, which uses values from an array (id_list) to specify the bound values.

```
create or replace procedure PRINT_EMPLOYEES
as
  cursor C_EMPLOYEES is
  select id, name, title, salary from EMPLOYEES ORDER BY id;
  type C_LIST is TABLE OF EMPLOYEES.id%type INDEX BY pls_integer;
  id_list C_LIST;
  COUNTER integer := 0;

begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sysdate);

  --Fill the array using values from cursor
  for EMP_REC in C_EMPLOYEES
  LOOP
    ID_LIST(COUNTER) := EMP_REC.id;
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
  end loop;

  --Outer loop goes from 1 to 3
  for OUTER_COUNTER in 1..3
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ID_LIST(OUTER_COUNTER) || ' ~ ' || ID_LIST(OUTER_COUNTER+5));

    --Inner loop runs from id_list (outer_counter) to id_list(outer_counter + 5)
    for counter in id_list(OUTER_COUNTER)..id_list(OUTER_COUNTER+5)
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ID_LIST(COUNTER));
    end LOOP;
  END LOOP;

end;
```

**References**:

1. [Associative Arrays on Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969)
2. [CURSOR FOR LOOP on Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php)
3. [Working with Collections on Oracle Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html) The `Code Listing 2: Display all strings in a collection` uses the first index value and the last index value of the array in the FOR loop (This examples shows another way to define the limits for the FOR loop).